# Finding the terms of sequence of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let {Sn} be the sequence defined by
First term of sequence=1,
Second term of sequence=1,
(n+1) th term of seq.
= n th term of seq.+ (n-1) th term of seq ....for n=3,4,5,...
Find 8th term of sequence.

Now I have the values of two terms already given.
I should find terms for n=3 onwards.
But the problem is that I am not getting how to compute the third term as the (n+1)th term can be calculated for n=3 according to the given formula.

Comment: your sequence is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only a matter of choosing $n$ in the relation :

$(n+1)$ th term of seq. = $n$ th term of seq.+ $(n-1)$ th term of seq

If you take $n=2$, that gives you :

$3$ th term of seq. $=$ $2$ th term of seq.+ $1$ th term of seq $= 1+1=2$

using $n=3$ you can find the 4th term, and so on.

Asumming we note $u_n$ the $n$th term, the relation is :

$$ u_{n+1}=u_n+u_{n-1}$$

and we use :
$$u_3=u_2+u_1 \quad (n=2)$$
$$u_4=u_3+u_2 \quad (n=3)$$
$$...$$
$$u_8=u_7+u_6 \quad (n=7)$$

Comment: But the formula of (n+1)th term of sequence is for n= 3,4,... then how can we take n=2 there?

Comment: @user5273591 think like this *the next $F_{n+1}$ is the sum of the two previous $F_n$ plus $F_{n-1}$*, this applied, gives you $F_2=F_1+F_0$

Comment: @user5273591 : Oh yeah didn't see the $n=3,4...$ It has to work for $n=2$ also otherwise you cannot do anything.

Comment: Yes, thats the reason why I have posted this question, it would have given for n=2,3,4,... it would be easy to find the answer

Comment: It comes to be 21, right?

Comment: @Kavita : yes it does